# CodeIgniter with or without Doctrine?

Tags: codeigniter, doctrine-orm, doctrine, codeigniter-2

I've used CodeIgniter with and without Doctrine. Honestly, I could not see great advantages in using Doctrine.

I'd like to know opinions about advantages in using CodeIgniter with or without Doctrine.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I honestly believe Doctrine 2 is a great object relational mapper which you can't forget.

Read the answer in here :- [Advantages of using Doctrine for PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4118731/advantages-of-using-doctrine-for-php)

Hope this helps,
Cheers!